After hours, a MyBatis query returns null. A JDBC query for the same data also returns null, but values are in the database
The given below query starts to return null after used for several hours. Given below the code using MyBatis
`<select id="selectMapiSession" parameterType="long" resultMap="mapiSessionMap">
    SELECT 
        mapi_session_id,
        scr_id,
        mapi_user_id,
        session_description,
        session_start_date,
        session_end_date,
        effective_date,
        expiration_date,
        mapi_repository_id
    FROM mapi_session
    WHERE mapi_session_id = #{mapiSessionID}
</select>`

I have done the same thing using plain JDBC, using native query system but it is also returning null. Given below is the code using jdbc
`ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
    Object bean = context.getBean("sqlSessionFactoryMAPI");
    
    SqlSessionFactory ses=(SqlSessionFactory) bean;
    DAO_RoutingDataSource dataSource = (DAO_RoutingDataSource) ses.getConfiguration().getEnvironment().getDataSource();
    
    String sql = "SELECT mapi_session_id scr_id,"
            + "         mapi_user_id,"
            + "         session_description,"
            + "         session_start_date,"
            + "         session_end_date,"
            + "         effective_date,"
            + "         expiration_date,"
            + "         mapi_repository_id"
            + "     FROM mapi_session"
            + "        WHERE mapi_session_id = ?";
    
    HashMap<String, Object> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
    
    try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
         PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql)) 
    {

        statement.setLong(1, Long.valueOf(mapiSessionId.toString()));
        
        try (ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery())
        {
            if (resultSet.next()) 
            {
                resultMap.put("scr_id", resultSet.getLong("scr_id"));
                resultMap.put("mapi_user_id", resultSet.getLong("mapi_user_id"));
                resultMap.put("session_description", resultSet.getString("session_description"));
                resultMap.put("session_start_date", resultSet.getDate("session_start_date"));
                resultMap.put("session_end_date", resultSet.getDate("session_end_date"));
                resultMap.put("effective_date", resultSet.getDate("effective_date"));
                resultMap.put("expiration_date", resultSet.getDate("expiration_date"));
                resultMap.put("mapi_repository_id", resultSet.getLong("mapi_repository_id"));
            }
        }
        catch (SQLException e) 
        {
            logger.error("< Fetching mapi session forcefully is not working >", e);
            throw e;
        }
    }
    
    if(resultMap!=null && !resultMap.isEmpty()) 
    {
        return resultMap;
    }
    return null;`

mybatis config file:
`






    <!--        <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="false"/>  -->
    
    <setting name="lazyLoadingEnabled" value="true"/>  
    <setting name="aggressiveLazyLoading" value="false"/>  
    <setting name="lazyLoadTriggerMethods" value="equals,clone,hashCode,toString"/>  
    <!-- <setting name="proxyFactory" value="CGLIB"/> -->
    <!-- <setting name="multipleResultSetsEnabled" value="true"/> -->
    <!-- <setting name="useColumnLabel" value="true"/> -->
    <!-- <setting name="useGeneratedKeys" value="false"/> -->
    <!-- <setting name="defaultStatementTimeout" value="25000"/> -->
    <!-- <setting name="safeRowBoundsEnabled" value="false"/> -->
    <!-- <setting name="localCacheScope" value="SESSION"/> -->
    <!-- <setting name="jdbcTypeForNull" value="OTHER"/> -->
</settings>

<typeAliases>
    <package
        name="com.oneshield.tools.dataaccess, com.oneshield.tools.domain, com.oneshield.tools.dto" />
</typeAliases>

`
DataSource getting used by both of them:
`<bean id="baseDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    abstract="true" scope="singleton" destroy-method="close">
    
    <property name="initialSize" value="0" /> <!-- Default: 0. The initial number of connections that are created when the pool is started.  -->
    
    <property name="maxActive" value="10" /> <!-- Default: 8. The maximum number of active connections that can be allocated 
                                                from this pool at the same time, or negative for no limit. -->
                                                
    <property name="maxIdle" value="8" /> <!-- Default: 8. The maximum number of connections that can remain idle in the pool, 
                                                without extra ones being released, or negative for no limit. If maxIdle is set too low on heavily 
                                                loaded systems it is possible you will see connections being closed and almost immediately new 
                                                connections being opened. This is a result of the active threads momentarily closing connections 
                                                faster than they are opening them, causing the number of idle connections to rise above maxIdle. 
                                                The best value for maxIdle for heavily loaded system will vary but the default is a good starting 
                                                point.-->
                                                
    <property name="minIdle" value="0" /> <!-- Default: 0. The minimum number of connections that can remain idle in the pool, 
                                                without extra ones being created, or zero to create none. -->
                                                
    <property name="maxWait" value="-1" /> <!-- Default: -1. The maximum number of milliseconds that the pool will wait (when there are 
                                                        no available connections) for a connection to be returned before throwing 
                                                        an exception, or -1 to wait indefinitely. -->
                                                        
    <property name="testOnBorrow" value="true" /> <!-- Default: true. The indication of whether objects will be validated before being borrowed 
                                                        from the pool. If the object fails to validate, it will be dropped from the pool, 
                                                        and we will attempt to borrow another. -->
                                                        
    <property name="validationQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" /> <!-- The SQL query that will be used to validate connections from this pool 
                                                                        before returning them to the caller. If specified, this query MUST be an 
                                                                        SQL SELECT statement that returns at least one row. If not specified, 
                                                                        connections will be validation by calling the isValid() method. -->
                                                                        
    <property name="connectionInitSqls" value="ALTER SESSION SET NLS_SORT=BINARY_CI" /> <!-- Default: null. A Collection of SQL statements that will 
                                                                                            be used to initialize physical connections when they are 
                                                                                            first created. These statements are executed only once
                                                                                             - when the configured connection factory creates 
                                                                                             the connection. -->                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

    <property name="timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis" value="300000" /> <!-- Default: -1. The number of milliseconds to sleep between runs of the 
                                                                            idle object evictor thread. When non-positive, no idle object evictor 
                                                                            thread will be run. -->

    <property name="minEvictableIdleTimeMillis" value="1800000" /> <!-- Default: 1800000. The minimum amount of time an object may sit idle in the 
                                                                        pool before it is eligible for eviction by the idle object evictor (if any). -->
                                                                        
    <property name="removeAbandoned" value="true" /> <!-- Default: false. Setting removeAbandonedOnMaintenance to true removes 
                                                                abandoned connections on the maintenance cycle (when eviction ends). This 
                                                                property has no effect unless maintenance is enabled by setting 
                                                                timeBetweenEvicionRunsMillis to a positive value.  -->
                                                                
    <property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="300" /> <!-- Default: 300. Timeout in seconds before an abandoned connection can be removed.  -->
</bean>`

I have tried replacing the BaseDataSource with ComboPooledDataSource but the issue still persists

Well, you just explained these information are irrelevant
I would suspect some logical error in your app like mishandled transaction.

Actually in server logs no error or exception is coming, it is just giving null
